# Como duplicar um banco de dados MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Existe alguma maneira de duplicar um banco de dados no `MYSQL` através da execução de alguma `query`?

Eu consigo copiar uma tabela com esse código:

```
CREATE TABLE table_2 AS SELECT * FROM table_1
```

Mas como fazer para copiar replicar um determinado banco de dados (no mesmo host)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível (e mais fácil) usando `mysqldump` por linha de comando:

```
mysqldump -h [servidor] -u root -e "create database banco_novo"
mysqldump -h [servidor] -u root banco_antigo|mysql -h [servidor] -u root banco_novo
```

No entanto existe alternativas com php e bash:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256328/1518921
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995186/1518921

Note que no PHP você pode executar linhas de comandos também, usando `exec()` por exemplo.

Comment: Gostei dessa técnica, vou adotar!

Answer (score 5):

Eu costumo fazer isso fora do phpMyAdmin, usando `mysqldump` no shell. Primeiro você faz um dump da base atual:

```
mysqldump -R --user=usuario --password=senha nomedabase > arquivo.sql
```

O `-R` é pra incluir procedures e funções no dump. Depois você cria uma base vazia (pode ser pelo MyAdmin ou qualquer client), e importa o dump de volta:

```
mysql --user=usuario --password=senha basedestino < arquivo.sql
```

Comment: Esse operador `<` funciona da mesma maneira que o `cat` do `terminal`?

Comment: O `cat` joga o conteúdo pra saída padrão. O `<` lê o arquivo pra entrada padrão.

Comment: Ótimo exemplo +1