# Exportar tabela para arquivo usando PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber se é possível eu exportar uma tabela do banco mysql em PHP de forma que eu consiga salvar em uma variável o script para criar essa tabela.

Igual ao PHPmyadmin, exportar a tabela para um arquivo sql.

Comment: É possivel sim amigo, vc tera que ter conhecimento para saber o código de exportaçao em sql , depois pesquise um comando no php que executa o comando na maquina como se fosse no terminal e é só colocar o comando de exportação dentro deste comando Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se a resposta lhe ajudou? Se não, informe poderia teve alguma duvida no uso dela.

Answer (score 3):

### Salvar banco via terminal

Se você quer apenas fazer um backup, então talvez não seja necessário PHP usar SSH e baixar pro pasta e depois usar o FTP pra fazer o download, o comando pra fazer o backup é este (conforme [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80239/3635)):

```
mysqldump -R --user=usuario --password=senha nomedabase > arquivo.sql
```

Ele vai salvar no teu servidor (se tiver usado SSH), então será necessário fazer download do sql posteriormente.

### Salvar banco com PHP

Você pode fazer isto usando php como descrito nesta resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31531996/1518921), com esta função (você pode criar um arquivo em incluir no teu script):

**exportdatabase.php**:

```
<?php
    function Export_Database($host, $user, $pass, $name, $charset, $tables=false, $backup_name=false)
    {
        set_time_limit(0);

        $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$name);
        $mysqli->set_charset($charset);

        $queryTables    = $mysqli->query('SHOW TABLES'); 
        while($row = $queryTables->fetch_row()) 
        { 
            $target_tables[] = $row[0]; 
        }   
        if($tables !== false) 
        { 
            $target_tables = array_intersect( $target_tables, $tables); 
        }
        foreach($target_tables as $table)
        {
            $result         =   $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);  
            $fields_amount  =   $result->field_count;  
            $rows_num=$mysqli->affected_rows;     
            $res            =   $mysqli->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table); 
            $TableMLine     =   $res->fetch_row();
            $content        = (!isset($content) ?  '' : $content) . "\n\n".$TableMLine[1].";\n\n";

            for ($i = 0, $st_counter = 0; $i < $fields_amount;   $i++, $st_counter=0) 
            {
                while($row = $result->fetch_row())  
                { //when started (and every after 100 command cycle):
                    if ($st_counter%100 == 0 || $st_counter == 0 )  
                    {
                            $content .= "\nINSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES";
                    }
                    $content .= "\n(";
                    for($j=0; $j<$fields_amount; $j++)  
                    { 
                        $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n", addslashes($row[$j]) ); 
                        if (isset($row[$j]))
                        {
                            $content .= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; 
                        }
                        else 
                        {   
                            $content .= '""';
                        }     
                        if ($j<($fields_amount-1))
                        {
                                $content.= ',';
                        }      
                    }
                    $content .=")";
                    //every after 100 command cycle [or at last line] ....p.s. but should be inserted 1 cycle eariler
                    if ( (($st_counter+1)%100==0 && $st_counter!=0) || $st_counter+1==$rows_num) 
                    {   
                        $content .= ";";
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $content .= ",";
                    } 
                    $st_counter=$st_counter+1;
                }
            } $content .="\n\n\n";
        }

        $backup_name = $backup_name ? $backup_name : $name.".sql";
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');   
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary'); 
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . $backup_name . '"');  
        echo $content;
        exit;
    }
```

Exemplo de uso, usando assim ele irá exportar todas tabelas:

```
include 'exportdatabase.php';

Export_Database('localhost', 'root', 'senha', 'bancodedados', 'utf8');
```

Se quiser exportar tabelas especificas use assim:

```
include 'exportdatabase.php';

$tabelas = array('tabela1', 'tabela2');
Export_Database('localhost', 'root', 'senha', 'bancodedados', 'utf8', $tabelas);
```

Se você não usa utf8, basta mudar o 5 parâmetro, por exemplo latin1:

```
include 'exportdatabase.php';

Export_Database('localhost', 'root', 'senha', 'bancodedados', 'latin1');
```

> **Nota** Eu adicionei o parâmetro `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` pra evitar um alto consumo de memória e adicionei `set_time_limit` pra evitar que o servidor cancele o download e adicionei a opção de trocar o charset.

Answer (score -2):

O que eu fiz 
1) desinstalei o xampp
2) Instalei novamente
3) Criei o mesmo banco de dados

Agora quando vou atualizar o Admin para abrir opencart da um monte de erro.

To preocupado pois este e commerce é da empresa como não consigo usar as pastas já feitas da opencart...

Comment: O local onde você publicou sua pergunta é apenas para respostas, sua mensagem poderia ser um comentário da pergunta. Sugiro que você abra uma pergunta própria explicando seu problema, porém antes leia [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)