# MySQL conexão perdida em While PHP

Tags: php, while

Faço uma **consulta** via ajax, mas, seu retorno está sendo:

> ```
> mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in
> mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header in
> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
> ```

Já adicionei no início do arquivo:

> ```php
> ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 9900);
> ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 9900);
> ```

mas, não surtiu efeito algum.
No SQL do while, a consulta é feita numa base com cerca de 250 mil registros.
Ao tentar executar o sql no heidisql o retorno é

> ```
> Lost connection to MySQL server during query
> ```

Exemplo de SQL

```sql
SELECT
id,nome,origem,cidade,telefone_residencial
FROM
mailing
INNER JOIN
atendimento_cep 
ON
atendimento_cep_cep = cep
WHERE
nome IS NOT NULL AND origem = 1
GROUP BY
id
ORDER BY
data_cadastro DESC
```

Comment: Poste mais detalhes da sua consulta e do seu while

Comment: veja se teu sql, está correto, veja se nao está quebrando indice na tabela,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O uso de `init_set` nem sempre vai ter efeito sobre o *php.ini*

O que creio ser o seu problema é que você criou uma query que esta trazendo muitos resultados, pois provavelmente você não esta usando `LIMIT`.

Outra possibilidade pode ser a quantidade de dados retornada no *buffer*, o que deve estar ultrapassando o `max_allowed_packet` (ou `max_packet_size`) configurado no `my.cnf`, no entanto isso na verdade pode ser também um problema em seu código, supondo que o seu `SELECT` ou na sua tabela, então os problemas podem ser:

- O SELECT esta trazendo muitas colunas e provavelmente colunas desnecessárias
- Você esta usando alguma coluna BLOB e nessa coluna você faz o upload de arquivos

Não tenho como afirmar ao certo qual o problema, poderia até dizer, edite o `my.cnf` e aumente os limites, ainda sim isso seria péssimo para o servidor, se você conseguir trabalhar dentro dos limites, mesmo que seja necessário aumentar só um pouco eles, será o ideal para que o seu servidor inteiro aguente quando houver muito trafego, agora se aumentar os limites do `timeout` e da quantidade de pacotes pode ser que o servidor se torne bastante lento para todos usuários.

Sobre o BLOB (se estiver usando) recomendo que leia isto:

- [É errado gravar byte de imagens no banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12687/3635)

Sobre o `SELECT` veja se realmente é necessário trazer todos os campos, não sei afirmar se é o *buffer* o problema, mas se precisa de todos os campos mesmo, então você pode experimentar usar o resultado sem buffer, assim `$mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM City", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)`:

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM tabela', MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

if ($result) {
   while ($row = $uresult->fetch_assoc()) {
       ...
   }
}

$uresult->close();
```

Para quem usa PDO faça isto:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=...;dbname=....', '...', '...');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);

$result = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM tabela');

if ($result) {
   while ($row = $uresult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Opa amigão, obrigado pelor retorno, na tabela não tem campo `blob`, na consulta só estou retornando 6 colunas, eu acho que o problema possa ser na qnt de dados, editei o post e adicionei um exemplo de sql, o meu é da mesma forma, só renomei-ei os campos para facilitar

Comment: @sNniffer o BLOB foi só uma teoria/exemplo de onde pode falhar, pode ser qualquer coisa que esta custando o tempo da requisição ou o limite dos dados, pode ser a falta de um LIMIT, como citei antes, só com mais detalhes vou poder apontar aonde é exatamente, todavia com as instruções que lhe passei se você observar o seu código poderá notar aonde esta o problema. A não ser que seja uma falha em alguma instalação do servidor mesmo e não no script em si.

Comment: Fala amigão, adicionei alguns indices nas tabelas, deu uma melhorada muito boa, eu não posso adicionar o limit, pois, a consulta é para exportação de dados direto. Obrigado pelas dicas

Comment: @sNniffer se é pra exportar veja se isto resolve: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80239/3635 ou isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80238/3635